# Assigning field values before saving on different models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I continue building my CakePHP application. Now I've created all the database schema in MySQL, run some "cake bake all" and I have lots of models, views and controllers, and I'm gonna personalize them.

In many of my models I have this fields:

- company_id
- created_by
- modified_by

As you can understand, the first field is the id of the owner of the "row", created_by is the id of who created the row and modified_by the latest person who updated it.

I know I can create a beforeSave filter in the model and update all the data (I suppose that I can know if I'm creating or updating a row, isn't it?), but just now I have 15 different models and I hope the app will grow more, so it's a lot of repetitive code to write. And, it breaks the DRY principle.

And my question is: Is there any "elegant" way to solve this problem? Maybe creating a class extending AppModel with a beforeSave filter for updating the fields, and that all my models inherit from the new Model class instead of AppModel?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a behaviour and load it for models that need that functionality.

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html#creating-behaviors

Answer (score 2):

I think the most appropriate way is to create Behaviors.

You can set up the beforeSave callback in the behavior like what you have in your model.

Here is the link to the documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html#behavior-callbacks

Answer (score 1):

You can also check as example dereuromark's [WhoDidItBehavior](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Model/Behavior/WhoDidItBehavior.php).